# PHP cURL add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header for specific endpoint

Tags: php, curl, cors

I have such code on my php server (5.2) endpoint `GET http://mydomain/get-code.php`:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $data = 'id=' . '123456' . '&' .
            'text=' . 'some text' . '&' .
            'code=' . urlencode($_GET['code']);
    $ch = curl_init('https://someapi.com/login/oauth');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match('/hash=([0-9a-f]+)/', $response, $out);
    echo $out[1];
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I'm requesting GET http://mydomain/get-code.php from another domain.

I'm getting CORS error in browser console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain/get-code.php No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9292' is therefore not allowed access.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't this header should come from the server side?

Comment: What is your issue ? cors is not related with the client.

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I'm requesting GET http://mydomain/get-code.php from another domain.

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks, I've added `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` but this didn't help

Comment: Also: when you say "doesn't work", what error are you ACTUALLY GETTING?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I'm getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain/get-code.php No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9292' is therefore not allowed access.` in browser console

Comment: @Kosmetika Have you added this on the SERVER side? It's not relevant on the part where you're making the GET request, it should be on the response headers that the server return from the GET request

Comment: @AlonEitan I have client on domain1 which makes GET request to domain2/get-code.php where domain2 makes request to third-party service and returns its value (see code above). The problem is with domain1 and domain2.

Comment: @Kosmetika You need to put in on domain2, not in domain1

Comment: @AlonEitan so I did - my domain2 code is in this question...

Comment: @AlonEitan but domain2 with `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` still returns CORS error to domain1, maybe I'm missing smth with configuration..

Comment: @Kosmetika  - Try to also include this header in domain2 `header("Allow:GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS");`

Comment: @RolandStarke see thread above, this doesn't help

Comment: that's strange but with `header` still CORS error in browser.. maybe additional server configuration?

Comment: @Kosmetika you can inspect the recived headers with the browser console.

Comment: @Kosmetika - The error still happens after you added both  `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` AND `header("Allow:GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS");` to domain2?

Comment: @RolandStarke that's what I receive `Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:278
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Thu, 28 Jan 2016 21:46:49 GMT
Location: mydomain
Server:nginx`

Comment: @Kosmetika My last attempt, try to add this header too `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, content-type, accept, origin, authorization, x-csrftoken");` (Additional help resource - http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Comment: I assume that problem might be in response status, when I make request from domain1 it returns 301 Moved Permanently status code but then resolves to 200.. is it because of curl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is for the server that is receiving the request, not the client sending the request.

Comment: You would need to add this to the mydomain/get-code.php page: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

Comment: You have to add it to the page that is being requested (the server), not from the client (where you are using curl)